# Cypress.io: Waiting for results of exec command

Tags: cypress

I am trying to set some variables based on the results of a `cy.exec()` command for use later in the script. For example:

```
cy.exec('some command').then((result) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(result.stdout)
  this.foo = json.foo
})
```

How can I wait for `this.foo` to be defined before proceeding with the rest of the script? I tried:

```
cy.exec('some command').as('results')
cy.wait('@results')
```

However `this.results` is undefined after the `cy.wait()` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need aliases. Your code is correct, but [you can't use `this` inside of a `() => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#No_separate_this). You should use a `function` declaration to make use of `this`.

Try this instead:

```js
cy.exec('some command').then(function(result) {
  let json = JSON.parse(result.stdout)
  this.foo = json.foo
})
```

Note that Cypress is asynchronous. What this means is that if you do something like this:

```js
cy.exec('some command').then(function(result) {
  let json = JSON.parse(result.stdout)
  this.foo = json.foo
})

expect(this.foo).to.eq(expectedStdout)
```

...your test will always fail. `this.foo = json.foo` will be executed *after* the `expect(this.foo)...` is evaluated.

If you want to use `this.foo` in this way, just use the Promise returned by [`cy.exec()`](https://on.cypress.io/exec):

```js
cy.exec('some command').then(result => {
  return JSON.parse(result.stdout)
})
.then(json => {
  // write the rest of your test here
  cy.get('blah').contains(json.something)
})
```

Comment: How can I reference the value of json.something in other tests outside of the "then" block?

Comment: You can't, it's asynchronous

Comment: You could return the Promise from the beforeEach, then it would run before your tests do

Comment: Ah, using a hook is the piece I was missing. The combination of putting my setup code in `before()` and not trying to use `this` in an arrow function was the solution for me.